# Replacing part of &str in Rust Vec

Tags: rust

I have written the following code:

```
use std::str::{from_utf8};

struct JSONPointer {
    segments: Vec<String>
}

fn build_json_pointer(s: Vec<String>) -> JSONPointer {
    JSONPointer { segments: s.iter().map(|x| x.replace("~1", "/").replace("~0", "~")).collect() }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string(), "baz~1".to_string()];
    let p = build_json_pointer(v);

    println!("Hello world! {:?}", p.segments);
}
```

This all works well with `String`s, but ideally my `JSONPointer` struct would contain a `Vec<&str>` (if only for learning purposes). The issue I run into takes place in the call to `map` the replaces a few reserved strings. No matter the combination of conversions I use, I am always told that my `borrowed value does not live long enough`.

I understand that I am taking a reference to a local value and trying to return it (leading to a possible use-after-delete error), but I can't seem to find a way to take a copy of the string.

**EDIT:** Updated to minimum reproducible form

I realize now that when I was referring to wanting a "copy" (heap allocated), that's exactly what `String` is. There was talk about a cleaner way of doing this possibly though.

Comment: I think that's not possible. `str::replace` returns a `String`, someone must own this string...

Comment: I think you could simplify your code further to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example: `nom` has probably nothing to do with your problem and thus this parsing code could be removed.

Comment: @Lukas Yep, sorry about that. @malbarbo You're right! I'm just being dense. The `String` is the heap allocated byte array I'm looking for. This is only doable with `String`

Comment: @Shepmaster You have your minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 4):

If you are worried about needlessly allocating strings, there is the possibility of using a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

struct JSONPointer<'a> {
    segments: Vec<Cow<'a, str>>,
}

fn replace_if<'a>(s: Cow<'a, str>, from: &str, to: &str) -> Cow<'a, str> {
    if s.contains(from) {
        Cow::Owned(s.replace(from, to))
    } else {
        s
    }
}

fn build_json_pointer<'a>(s: &[&'a str]) -> JSONPointer<'a> {
    let segments = s
        .iter()
        .copied()
        .map(Cow::Borrowed)
        .map(|x| replace_if(x, "~1", "/"))
        .map(|x| replace_if(x, "~0", "~"))
        .collect();

    JSONPointer { segments }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["foo", "bar", "baz~1"];
    let p = build_json_pointer(&v);

    println!("Hello world! {:?}", p.segments);
}
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't need to allocate *any* memory when no replacements need to be made, but has the downside that each pattern has be be searched twice. It could potentially be even more efficient with a structure like a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)).

For your original case that accepted a `String`, you could do something similar without `Cow` by keeping the original `String` and not unconditionally replacing it:

```
struct JSONPointer {
    segments: Vec<String>,
}

fn replace_if(s: String, from: &str, to: &str) -> String {
    if s.contains(from) {
        s.replace(from, to)
    } else {
        s
    }
}

fn build_json_pointer(s: &[String]) -> JSONPointer {
    let segments = s
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .map(|x| replace_if(x, "~1", "/"))
        .map(|x| replace_if(x, "~0", "~"))
        .collect();

    JSONPointer { segments }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string(), "baz~1".to_string()];
    let p = build_json_pointer(&v);

    println!("Hello world! {:?}", p.segments);
}
```